# Translation Golf XLII - Alanis Morissette

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

For this edition of Translation Golf, I picked an excerpt from Alanis Morissette's song You Owe Me Nothing in Return:

---

> *I'll give you countless amounts of outright acceptance if you want it.*
>
> *I will give you encouragement to choose the path that you want if you need it.*
>
> *You can speak of anger and doubts, your fears and freak outs, and I'll hold it.*
>
> *You can share your so-called shame-filled accounts of times in your life and I won't judge it.*
>
> <sub>(253 characters.)</sub>

A (slightly modified) translation by Google Translator:

> *Te daré innumerables cantidades de absoluta aceptación si lo deseas.*
>
>  *Te daré ánimo para elegir el camino que quieras si lo necesitas.*
>
>  *Puedes hablar de la ira y las dudas, de tus miedos y de tus pánicos, y yo lo retendré.*
>
>  *Puedes compartir los momentos de tu vida que creas llenos de vergüenza y no los juzgaré.*
>
>  <sub>(247 characters.)</sub>

My own translation:

> *Si quieres, aceptaré todo de ti sin medida.*
>
>  *Si hace falta, te animaré a ir adonde digas.*
>
>  *Lidiaré con los espantos y enojos que tengas.*
>
>  *Y no juzgaré las historias que te apenan.*
>
>  <sub>(138 characters.)</sub>

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

- See the [rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481).
- Here's the [letter counter](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/).

Comment: @walen no podía esperar así que he incluido yo una traducción generada (aunque ligeramente corregida) por un traductor automático. :-D

Comment: Gana Peter Taylor *por su versión en 37 caracteres*, porque conserva cada uno de los sentidos originales. Admitir las versiones más cortas sería como traducir todo el texto de la Divina Comedia en "Morir es feo".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En orden de longitud, para que se vea cómo he llegado a la versión más corta (y por lo tanto de más libre interpretación).

#### 37 caracteres

> Te acepto, te dejo libre, te escucho sin juzgar

#### 24 caracteres

> Conmigo no tienes que fingir

#### 18 caracteres

> Conmigo puedes ser tú

El voseo argentino permite ahorrar el cambio de vocal pero compensa en el pronombre:

> Conmigo podés ser vos

#### 11 caracteres

> Te dejo ser tú

NB la letra original está claramente en plan indicativo. Es una oferta y no un mandamiento, así que no valdría *«Sé tú»*.

Comment: Gana Peter Taylor *por su versión en 37 caracteres*, porque conserva cada uno de los sentidos originales. Admitir las versiones más cortas sería como traducir todo el texto de la Divina Comedia en "Morir es feo".

Answer (score 2):

#### 95 caracteres

> Te aceptaré sin fin y animaré a elegir tu senda si quieres. No te juzgaré si me hablas de tu ira, duda, pánico o vergüenza.

Answer (score 2):

#### 67

> ¿Quieres [mil](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PENxPxR#ApszP1b) [plácets](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TII1OPe)? ¿Ánimo para [tomar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZzcN8W0#M8vrOAv) rumbo? ¿Hablar de tu [sentir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XbVfLnt) sin [apuro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3LmP7tP#1RqFngD)? Te lo doy.

Answer (score 2):

#### 98 caracteres

> De ti acepto todo sin condición.
>
> Te animo a ir donde quieras.
>
> Tu ira y miedos retengo.
>
> Por mi no guardes lo que te avergüenza.